# Ext.Net toolbar button background color (incorrect in IE)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, extjs, ext.net

I have a ViewPort with a Panel having a TopBar.

CSS part

```
 .mytoolbar .x-btn-default-toolbar-small
 {
        border-style:none;
        background-color:blue;
 }
```

ASPX:

```
       <ext:Panel runat="server" Layout="HBoxLayout" ID="TestPanel" Region="Center" BodyStyle="border-style:none;">
          <LayoutConfig>
             <ext:HBoxLayoutConfig Align="Stretch"></ext:HBoxLayoutConfig>
          </LayoutConfig>
          <TopBar>
             <ext:Toolbar runat="server" Cls="mytoolbar" Flat="true" ClassicButtonStyle="false" MinHeight="40">
                <Items>
                   <ext:Button runat="server" ID="btnTest" Text="Test"></ext:Button>
                </Items>
             </ext:Toolbar>
                </TopBar>
            </ext:Panel>
```

The background color is indeed blue in Firefox and Chrome, but gray in Internet Explorer 11.

How to fix this in IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent many hours trying to get to the bottom of this and I found the answer after reading this post on the [Ext.Net Forums](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?23924-Change-the-panel-s-color-border&p=106105&viewfull=1#post106105).

I had to add background-image:none; to the CSS.

```
 .mytoolbar .x-btn-default-toolbar-small
 {
        border-style:none;
        background-color:#004191;
        background-image:none;
 }
```

I hope this will save someone the trouble I had to go through.